# Why is $G/ \ker f$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\, $ be a homomorphism. Then, I know that $ \ker f$ is a normal closed subgroup in $G$. Why is $G/ \ker f$  abelian?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I suppose $G$ is a topological group, and $f$ is a continuous homomorphism?

Comment: I know I can glean this information from the words you use later (like "normal closed subgroup"), but it would still be nice if you could be explicit about the fact that $G$ is a group (is it topological? Not that it matters in this case) and that $\Bbb R$ has the operation of addition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The isomorphism theorem says $G/\ker f \cong \operatorname{img} f ⊆ ℝ$ and subgroubs of abelian groups are abelian.

Comment: thanks a lot :)